# Div Messes Up After Exceeding Main Div Height

Tags: html, css, css-float

So I've been working on this website for a while now, but I've ran into a problem. It's kind of hard to explain so first I'm gonna show a screenshot of it: 
[image]
As you can see, I can keep stacking my sidebox divs, but once it goes past the main div, for some reason it goes directly to the right of the sidebox div above it.
I've tried different ways of fixing, but I have yet to succeed.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<!--Navigation-->
<div id="sidebox">
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<a href=""><li>HOME</li></a>
<a href=""><li>REGISTER</li></a>
<a href=""><li>DOWNLOADS</li></a>
<a href=""><li>CHAT BOX</li></a>
<a href=""><li>FORUM</li></a>
<a href=""><li>RANKINGS</li></a>
<a href=""><li>DONATE</li></a>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<!--Banner-->
<div id="banner"></div>

<!--Main Content-->
<div id="main">

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!--Server Information-->
<div id="sidebox">

</div>

<!--Partners-->
<div id="sidebox">

</div>

<div id="sidebox">

</div>

<div id="sidebox">

</div>

<div id="sidebox">

</div>

<div id="sidebox">

</div>

<div id="sidebox">

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-image: url('../img/bg.png');
}

#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
}

#banner {
    width:712px;
    height:175px;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid black;
    outline: 2px solid #444;
    margin-bottom:14px;
    float:right;
}

#sidebox {
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid black;
    outline: 2px solid #444;
    width:230px;
    min-height:100px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:14px;
}

#nav {
    font-family: arial;
    background:red;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav ul li {
    background: url('../img/navbg.jpg');
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    border-bottom: #262626 solid;
    border-top: #262626 solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#nav ul li:hover{
    background: url('../img/navbghov.jpg');
}

#nav ul a {
    color: #808080;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main {
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid black;
    outline: 2px solid #444;
    float:right;
    width:712px;
    min-height:600px;
}

.clear {

}
```

Comment: Okay. So..? what's wrong..? what's the expected behavior..?

Comment: please provide a fiddle or a link to the website

Answer (score 1):

Hello you have to use additional wrapper check this bin http://jsbin.com/sowivuvi/1/

there are two more divs `#sidebar, #content`

Comment: I was getting ready to make the same suggestion.  Adding the extra divs separates out the page like I assume the OP has indended.  The side by side boxes is because the `main` div isn't pushing the sideboxes over anymore.